# Eclipse Neon Missing Working set Icon

Tags: eclipse

Spec : Eclipse Neon (eclipse-jee-neon-R-win32-x86_64 ) ,Jdk1.8

Working set Icon is missing on Installing the Eclipse Neon.

Problem : All of the Projects are displayed irrespective of the Working set Assigned, also the icon for Selection Assign set is missing.

Is this a Generic Problem  or something am i missing?

Comment: Missing where? What view or menu are you looking at?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the Project Explorer which manages working set a bit differently from Package Explorer (that you might be more used to). Additionally to selecting `Top-Level Elements > Working Set`, you have to choose the selected working set via the view menu > `Select working sets...`.

Comment: Project Explorer or Package Explorer or Navigator ...All of these are MISSING of the  'Working Set'  feature.  I have the latest Zip installed and using JDK1.8